# WakefulBroadcastReceiver get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

In my Android project, I have a `Service` class:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
   ...

   //Defined a WakefulBroadcastReceiver as a inner static class
   public static class DeviceRebootReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              //Do something when user reboot the device
        }
  }

}
```

As you see above, I have defined a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` as a **inner static class** in `MyService` class. This receiver receives the broadcast when user reboot his/her device.

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.project"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="2.1" >

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

   <application
     ...>
      <activity ...> ... </activity>

      <service android:name="com.my.project.MyService"
               android:exported="false"/>

       <receiver
            android:name="com.my.project.MyService$DeviceRebootReceiver"
          >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

But when I run my app & after rebooted the device, my logcat shows me error:

```
Unable to instantiate receiver com.my.project.MyService$DeviceRebootReceiver: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.my.project.MyService$DeviceRebootReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.my.project-1.apk]
```

Why my receiver class is not able to be loaded by system?

**=====Update======**

I also tried to make my `DeviceRebootReceiver` as a **separate** class (*DeviceRebootReceiver.java*), and made the `AndroidManifest.xml` changed to :

```
 <application...>
    <receiver
      android:name="com.my.project.DeviceRebootReceiver"
          >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
           </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
</application>
```

But I still get the similar error in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.my.project.DeviceRebootReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Comment: is your service running when rebooted device? probably it;s because your service is dead when rebooted and so the sub class cannot be reached and not found exception!

Comment: @Saqib, I also tried to put my DeviceRebootReceiver in its own class file, but the similar error still rise. Please check my update.

Comment: hmm, have you tried adding ' android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" '

Comment: As you see in my post, I have that permission too.

Comment: then it looks some IDE kind of issue, try restarting your IDE or system n try again

Comment: Are you sure the fully qualified class name of your class is `com.my.project.Xxxx`? Look at the `package` line in your class.

Comment: I am quite sure all those path,package names are correct. I have double checked again.

Comment: i guess you missed your project reference in ur bootLoader service as     <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="your.package" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: This is very weird, after I changed from WakefulBroadcastReceiver to BroadcastReceiver , it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it.

It's about the **android-support-v4.jar** library, you should only have the official and updated library (copied from ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/support/) under the libs folder in your project and **Android Private Libraries** checked in the Java Build Path of your project. For example, I also had a **ClassNotFoundException** because of my project was using the **android-support-v4.jar** of another library (**ActionBarSherlock**) even with the official android-support-v4.jar included in my java build path, so I unchecked the **Android Private Libraries** of the ActionBarSherlock project to avoid this redundancy.